# How to set all elements of pytorch tensor to zero after a certain index in the given axis, where the index is given by another pytorch tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch, vectorization

I've two PyTorch tensors

```
mask = torch.ones(1024, 64, dtype=torch.float32)
indices = torch.randint(0, 64, (1024, ))
```

For every `i`th row in `mask`, I want to set all the elements after the index specified by `i`th element of `indices` to zero. For example, if the first element of `indices` is `50`, then I want to set `mask[0, 50:]=0`. Is it possible to achieve this without using for loop?

Solution with for loop:

```
for i in range(mask.shape[0]):
    mask[i, indices[i]:] = 0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can first generate a tensor of size (1024x64) where each row has numbers arranged from 0 to 63. Then apply a logical operation using the indices reshaped as (1024x1)

```
mask = torch.ones(1024, 64, dtype=torch.float32)
indices = torch.randint(0, 64, (1024, 1))    # Note the dimensions

mask[torch.arange(0, 64, dtype=torch.float32).repeat(1024,1) >= indices] = 0
```

Comment: Amazing! I was able to further simply this as `mask = (torch.arange(0, 64, dtype=torch.float32).repeat(1024,1) < indices).float()`